# Conformability and Matrix Derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the formula for the derivative of the product of two matrices when they are different sizes? Further, what is the formula for the derivative of a Hadamard product when the derivatives of the inputs aren't the same size as the inputs?

Here's what I'm thinking: assume an $n\times 1$ vector $x$, a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix $S$, $f(x)=Sw$, $g(x)=w'Sw$, $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, and $j(x)=\operatorname{had}(x, h(x))$ where $\operatorname{had}(a, b)$ is the Hadamard product between the two vectors.

For $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ the derivatives are $S$ and $2\cdot Sw$, respectively. One would think that the derivative of $h(x)$ would be $\dfrac{g(x)f'(x)-g'(x)f(x)}{g(x)^2}$ from the quotient rule. However, the numerator is $n\times n$ and the second part is multiplying a $n\times 1$ vector by an $n\times 1$ vector, which doesn't work.

Similarly, I found a formula for the derivative of Hadamard product and applying it to this would give $\operatorname{had}(x, h'(x)) + \operatorname{had}(I, h(x)) =\operatorname{had}(x, h'(x)) + h(x)$. Since $h(x)$ is $n\times 1$, $h'(x)$ must be $n\times n$. However, the Hadamard product of an $n\times 1$ and $n\times n$ matrix doesn't work. Similarly, the opposite is the case in the second term. So far as I can tell, the terms that are $n\times 1$ need to be copied over to become $n\times n$. This would indicate that the proper formula is something like $\operatorname{had}(\operatorname{kron}(x,\operatorname{ones}),h'(x))+\operatorname{had}(I,\operatorname{kron}(h(x),\operatorname{ones}))$, where $I$ is an $n\times n$ identity matrix and ones is a $1\times n$ vector of ones.

I think that's on the right track since I found [a matrix calculus guide](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~pfackler/MatCalc.pdf) that connects the problem to Kronecker products.
However, I still had the problem of conformability when using their product rule formula.

Comment: I think that you mean *Hadamard*... Capital H.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has provided the answers to me.

He noted that $g'(x)$ is $1 \times n$ not $n \times 1$ so there is no conformability problem with $h'(x)$. Second, the derivative of the Hadamard product $f(x) \circ g(x)$ is $\operatorname{diag}(g(x)) f'(x) + \operatorname{diag}(f(x)) g'(x)$.